# jQuery Selector Issue When Binding to DOMSubtreeModified

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a simple chrome extension for facebook.  Can anyone give a hand?  The last console.log line says undefined.  I'm sure the anchor is not selected, I just don't know how to fix it.

```
$("a").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {  
if(left($("a").href,60)==="http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com"){
    var strPath=$("a").href;
    strPath=right(strPath,strPath.len-32);

    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('href',"strPath");
    aTag.innerHTML = "VIEW IN HD";
    $("#a").parentNode.appendChild(aTag);
}else{console.log($("a").href);}
```

})

Comment: I'm curious as to what is going on here...`$('a').href` is not valid, it would need to be `$('a')[0].href` to get dom element and not jquery object, or `$('a').prop('href')`, also, what is `left()` function ?  and why are you using `===` operator for comparison of string ? facebook uses `https` not `http` so you should make that adjustment to your own code

Comment: @Ohgodwhy When the subtree of the anchor is modified, how do I refer to that anchor in the function?  Is it just adding the [0]?

Left is defined elsewhere.  It is the VB style left that returns the left x characters in a string.

About the ===, should it be something else?  I thought one (=) was to set, two was to compare datatypes, and three for datatype and data.  Is that not it?

Comment: The DOM element as opposed to the jQuery element is `$('a')[0]` whereas the cachable reference to the jQuery element is `$('a')` but I believe what you really want is `this` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for your help.  I've got a simplified test working that changes the href on hover, but it does not work immediately.  If I just let it sit there for about 30 seconds, it works.  I think it has something to do with Facebook being so dynamic.  I've tried setting the "run_at" properties to both start and idle, but the result is the same.  Any idea how to apply changes to anchors immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in JQuery, any information included between tags is considered as attributes. 
Example,

```
<span id="xyz-123" data="toggle"> </span>
```

and `data` can be accessed by using the [**attr**](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$("#xyz-123").attr("data")
```

And in your case

```
 $("a").attr("href")
```

and you can set it by passing the new value as a second parameter.

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://somesite.com")
```

But I would suggests you give the a a unique id, or a class to group it.